# peewee bulk_update not updating any records

Tags: peewee

I'm running the following, and while I'm not receiving any errors, the database (MySQL) doesn't update. I'm running peewee v3.14.10 and PyMySQL v1.0.2 on Python v3.9.7. All the other calls using peewee work (eg. query, update, etc.) without any issues.

```
# query Word model with only result words
words = Word.select(Word.word, Word.queried, Word.updated).where(Word.word << result_words)

# update word in words
for word in words:
    word.queried = word.queried + 1
    word.updated = datetime.now()

# debug
for word in words:
    print(word.word, word.queried, word.updated)

# bulk update queried counters on Words model
do_atomic = db.database
batch_size = 50
with do_atomic.atomic():
    Word.bulk_update(words, fields=[Word.word, Word.queried, Word.updated], batch_size=batch_size)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also no need to do this in Python. Why don't you use a proper update query?

```
(Word
 .update(queried=Word.queried + 1, updated=datetime.now)
 .where(Word.word << list_of_words)
 .execute())
```

`bulk_update()` also is working fine as far as I can tell:

```
db = MySQLDatabase('peewee_test')

class Word(Model):
    word = CharField()
    queried = IntegerField()
    updated = DateTimeField()
    class Meta:
        database = db

Word.insert_many([
    ('w%d' % i, i,  datetime.datetime.now())
    for i in range(10)]).execute()

words = Word.select().where(Word.word << ['w1', 'w3', 'w5', 'w7', 'w9'])
for word in words:
    word.queried += 1
    word.updated = datetime.datetime.now()

with db.atomic():
    Word.bulk_update(words, fields=[Word.word, Word.queried, Word.updated],
            batch_size=3)

for w in Word.select().order_by(Word.word):
    print(w.word, w.queried, w.updated)
```

Output:

```
w0 0 2022-06-28 10:47:43
w1 2 2022-06-28 10:47:43
w2 2 2022-06-28 10:47:43
w3 4 2022-06-28 10:47:43
w4 4 2022-06-28 10:47:43
w5 6 2022-06-28 10:47:43
w6 6 2022-06-28 10:47:43
w7 8 2022-06-28 10:47:43
w8 8 2022-06-28 10:47:43
w9 10 2022-06-28 10:47:43
```

Comment: Thanks! The 'proper update query' is sufficiently fast for my purposes. For the life of me, I can't figure out why bulk_update isn't working for me (I have it working in other Flask webapps).